# Eulerian path, directed graph

Tags: perl, graph

Good evening. I'm really a beginner, and I am working in an implementation of an Eulerian path. That means that every edge (not a vertex) of a directed graph has to be used only once.
For some reason it doesn't manage to go over all vertices even if in paper it should. It seems to ignore half of the vertices or simply not adding them to the circuit.

The expected outcome is:

```
6->7->8->9->6->3->0->2->1->3->4
```

Nevertheless, the outcome I get is:

```
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

What i have as code is the following:

```
my %edges={'6'=>['3','7'],'8'=>['9'],'1'=>['3'],'0'=>['2'],'3'=>['0','4'], '7' =>['8'],'9'=>['6'],'2'=>['1']}; 


    my $startvertex=6; #this i got from additional code
    my $location=$startvertex;
    my @stack = ($startvertex);
    my @circuit  = ();

        while (@stack)
        {
            if (@{$edges{$location}}[0])
                {
                    push @stack, $location;
                    my $newlocation=@{$edges{$location}}[0];
                    splice @{$edges{$location}},0,1;
                    $location=$newlocation;

                }
            else
                {
                push @circuit, $location;
                $location=pop @stack;
                } 

        }   

my @revcircuit= reverse @circuit;
print @revcircuit;
```

Thank you very much in advance for your insight.

Comment: `{...}` defines a hash reference, not a hash. I can't run your code as presented here.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I don't know why but I can run it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if (@{$edges{$location}}[0])
```

One of your nodes is called `0` which is false in Perl. Therefore, once the zero node is reached, the program continues as if there were no more nodes.
Use [defined](http://p3rl.org/defined) instead.

Here's a working version, slightly edited (e.g. removed unnecessary array dereference):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %edges = ( 6 => [3, 7],
              8 => [9],
              1 => [3],
              0 => [2],
              3 => [0, 4],
              7 => [8],
              9 => [6],
              2 => [1]);

my $startvertex = 6;

my $location = $startvertex;
my @stack = ($startvertex);
my @circuit;

while (@stack) {
    if (defined $edges{$location}[0]) {
        push @stack, $location;
        $location = shift @{ $edges{$location} };
    } else {
        push @circuit, $location;
        $location = pop @stack;
    }
}
my @revcircuit = reverse @circuit;
print "@revcircuit\n";
```

Also note that it uses round parentheses to define the `%edges` hash. Curly braces introduce a hash reference, with them I'm getting

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at ./1.pl line 5.
```

Comment: Oh god, thanks a lot!! works really nicely. I appreciate it enormously, really.

Comment: How can I give you points or something? you saved my assignment :)

Comment: @MarthaElenaIbarra you can click on the green tick next to the answer (and upvote it as well)